# start a program from python and not wait for it to exit

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\FZV3H2\Desktop\a.vbs")
print("hello")
```

** I want the execution control to go to print("hello") as soon as the execution of "a.vbs" starts , and not wait for "a.vbs" terminate before going to next line . **

Comment: `os.startfile` doesn't wait for the command to exit, so you already have what you need.

Comment: Your code should work as is. Could you clarify you question? [`os.startfile()` returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
os.system(r"start C:\Users\FZV3H2\Desktop\a.vbs")
```

This does wait for the program to finish loading, but when I use it to launch an excel file, program execution continues even if excel file remains open.

Alternatively, use `subprocess`

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen( [ "foo.exe", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3" )
```

Comment: Why do you think this is better than the code OP already uses?

Comment: @interjay I have tried using `os.P_NOWAIT` but no luck since apparently `os.spawnlp` does not exist for python on Windows. If OP wants a platform agnostic solution, he will need to go with subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) library. Popen will not wait for a return code.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

proc = Popen([r"C:\Users\FZV3H2\Desktop\a.vbs"])
```

If you want to get the result of calling the command you can redirect the output to stdout.

```
proc = Popen([r"C:\Users\FZV3H2\Desktop\a.vbs"],stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Then access later using `proc.communicate()`. Popen will work on most platforms where startfile is a windows specific command.

Comment: Why do you think this is better than the code OP already uses?

Comment: @interjay, so you recommend using the os methods over subprocess? Also does `os.startfile` work on every platform?

Comment: does it actually run the script on Windows? Have you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

You need [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) from subprocess module of python

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen([r"C:\Users\FZV3H2\Desktop\a.vbs"])
```

If you want it to be executed in a shell environment, give `shell=True` with the Popen. However, **this is not recommended**

If your vbs file requires the environment and path variables set up, you will need the `shell=True`. Like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen(r"C:\Users\FZV3H2\Desktop\a.vbs", shell=True)
```

This is the equivalent of your example with the startfile. Like double clicking on the file in the explorer. Both resembles

```
cmd.exe /c start C:\Users\FZV3H2\Desktop\a.vbs
```

However, avoid `shell=True` wherever you can as it can lead you to [shell injection attacks](http://www.golemtechnologies.com/articles/shell-injection).

In case, you do not wish to go with `shell=True` option and gets a WindowsError or a OSError, you can call the cscript.exe or wscript.exe depending on which one is registered to run your vb scripts.

```
In the command prompt, run these:
C:\>assoc .vbs
```

This gives you the name in which an exe is registered to run the vbs(something like `.vbs=...`). Since you were using startfile successfully until now, this should give you some value. Now pass that value to the `ftype command to get the absolute executable location.

```
C:\>ftype `Output of assoc goes here`
```

This will give you the cscript.exe location or wscript.exe location. Use that with the `Popen`

```
Popen([r".exe location here", r".vbs location here"])
```

Comment: When I started answering, it was not there :-) difference in minutes I guess. I added the `shell` option is required if he needs to execute things in shell environment. Even though it is not recommended, it is required in some cases :-)

Comment: I am using this code on windows and it doesn't work .    did u try it ... thanks 4 d assistance by d way

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/FZV3H2/Desktop/ser2.py", line 7, in <module>
    Popen([r"C:\Users\FZV3H2\Desktop\b.vbs"])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1111, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: This error is raised when the file extension is generally not executable(in your case, vbs is not associated with an executable). You can go with the second option of using `shell=True`, which will run the application or you have to call it like the third option, like `Popen(["cmd.exe", r"/c", "start", r"C:\Users\FZV3H2\Desktop\a.vbs"])`. Both will execute your file fine :-)

Comment: You can check whether the file type is associated as executable in command prompt through `assoc` command and `ftype` command